# Exclude @types typings in installed dependencies

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to exclude global typings in installed dependencies?

I installed a local dependency. This also copied the node_modules folder of that dependency. This node_modules folder holds installed @types typings. These conflict with the @types typings installed for the main project.

Eg. `project-path/node_modules/local-dependency/node_modules/@types/react` conflicts with `project-path/node_modules/@types/react`.

Is it possible to make the typescript compiler ignore the typings in that local dependency?

Comment: I've answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54601112). I fixed the issue by specifying `./node_modules/@types/*` in the `paths` key of my `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude \`node\_modules/@types/\*\*/node\_modules\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530597/how-to-exclude-node-modules-types-node-modules)

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, use `"skipLibCheck": true` in the compiler options.

Answer (score 7):

Did you try to use an empty array for `types` option?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "types": []
  }
}
```

This disables automatic inclusion of types.

See the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) for more details.

Answer (score -4):

You may be able to use the `include` and `exclude` properties in your tsconfig.json for more fine-grained control over what files the TypeScript compiler includes:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

> The `"include"` and `"exclude"` properties take a list of glob-like file patterns. The supported glob wildcards are:
>
> - * matches zero or more characters (excluding directory separators)
> - ? matches any one character (excluding directory separators)
> - **/ recursively matches any subdirectory

So perhaps you could do something like:

```
{

    ...    

    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Or, depending on yours needs, you could design a more targeted glob pattern that only excludes the `node_modules` directory of the one dependency giving you problems.

If you have control over the `local-dependency` module in your example, a better solution would be to update either the dependency or your app to use the same the version of the `@types/react` module, delete your npm modules, and do a fresh `npm install`.  This should allow npm to install a single, shared version of the module, removing any possibility for conflicts.

Comment: I tried putting `"exclude": ["node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"]` but it doesn’t make a difference. It seems that `node_modules/@types` is special—the only way to do an exclusion is to use the `types` property and explicitly include everything except what I don’t want which means updating the list every time an indirect dependency changes. I.e., there might not be support in TypeScript for exclusion for `node_modules/@types`. If there is, this isn’t it.