# When I npm runbuild in vue.js get the error Interface 'NodeRequire' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Require'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

```
ERROR in C:/phpStudy2018/PHPTutorial/WWW/Tms.Web/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(139,11):
139:11 Interface 'NodeRequire' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Require' and 'RequireFunction'.
  Named property 'cache' of types 'Require' and 'RequireFunction' are not identical.
    137 |
    138 | // For backwards compability
  > 139 | interface NodeRequire extends NodeJS.Require {}
        |           ^
    140 | interface RequireResolve extends NodeJS.RequireResolve {}
    141 | interface NodeModule extends NodeJS.Module {}
    142 |

 error  in C:/phpStudy2018/PHPTutorial/WWW/Tms.Web/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts

ERROR in C:/phpStudy2018/PHPTutorial/WWW/Tms.Web/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(139,11):
```

My environment is vue.js + typescript. I don't know if I have any problems with my configuration or with the third-party package
Can you give me some useful advice
Thank you

Answer (score 23):

I had same problem.

the version of @types/node was 13.1.0
released at Mon, 23 Dec 2019 16:40:55 GMT

in my case, it's working when I use former version 12.12.22

`npm install --save-dev @types/node@12.12.22`

Comment: You should also use `--save-exact` flag or otherwise `package.json` gets this line: `"@types/node": "^12.12.22"` instead of the exact version `"12.12.22"`

Comment: follow this issue. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41224

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to exclude the `@types` definitions from the compilation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57113847/1704895

It's amazing simple ( tsconfig.json ):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "types": []
  }
}
```